# Can't focus UITextField in nested UIView

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, interface-builder, xib

My storyboard has a scene which has a `UIView` dragged from the library with a custom class `RegisterView` applied. The implementation class for `RegisterView` contains the following override which loads a XIB for the view:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("RegisterView", owner: self, options: nil)    
}
```

The XIB has three text fields (name, email, password) that have again been dragged onto the XIB from the library.

No properties have been changed on any views, other than applying a custom class to the UIView in the storyboard scene.

The XIB is loaded successfully and I see the text fields, however I cannot focus any of these fields. They're enabled and both the custom view and the text fields have "User Interaction Enabled" checked.

Why can't the fields receive focus?

Comment: Are you testing with the simulator?

Comment: Yes, placing a UITextField in the parent view (the storyboard scene) can be focused and the keyboard appears.

Comment: And did you try to change the RegisterView to a normal UIView to rule that out?

Comment: Did you ever figured it out? I ran into the same problem.

Comment: @ASP sorry - no I didn't.